# Android and battery issue

Tags: battery

Recently purchased a new cord and box.
It is now flashing on/off on the battery feature.
Help
It is also not holding the charge

Comment: What android device are you using ? .. Version, Etc... Have you damaged the charger port, has it had water damage ? ... Is the "Box" a new Adapter ? ... .. The Adapter may be the wrong voltage .. Your device might require a stronger one, or hopefully not for you sake, a weaker one...

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S5

Comment: Cord and adapter where just purchased at my local tech shop.

Comment: Whey you are talking about "cord and box" you mean an USB charger and an USB cable, right?

Answer (score 0):

The question needs to be more explained! But still, I will try to answer your question.

If you have recently bought it and you are facing problem then there is a strong chance that you have got a faulty product. And you can't recognize the problem by your self because it's more likely faulty in hardware. So, what I recommend is to try another charger if you have it already or just spend a few dollars to get a new one.

Also, there may be a software glitch that preventing the charging. Try to update or reset the phone. Doing these will give it a fresh kick. And if you are still not fixed then I highly recommend following my one of the article. I have pretty much explained about [battery issues along with fixes](https://www.rogtechs.com/save-battery-power/).